# Azure AD and SQL Login/User not working after ID changed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, user-accounts

I have a .NET core MVC application I inherited that has an Azure SQL back end. Typically I create account like this:
CREATE USER [MyNewUser@Something.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER where MyNewUser was previously created on the Azure AD.

Recently an existing user's AAD account was changed from something like:
MyUse@domain.com to MyUser@domain.com NOTE the additional "r" to make MyUse into MyUser

When I try to create the SQL USER like I typically do >> CREATE USER [MyUser@domain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER I get the error message:
"The login already has an account under a different user name"

The user can no longer access the .NET core application. How can I fix the access for the AAD account MyUser?

Comment: "the additional "e" to make MyUse into MyUser" - don't you mean an additional "r"?

Comment: "The user can no longer access the .NET core application. How can I fix the access for the AAD account MyUser?" - what SQL Server auth settings are in your connection-string? How is the application taking the user's AAD access-token and passing it to SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, thanks I mean "r" not "e". Basically the stuff in front of the @ was change to make the users last name correct. I'll edit my post. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dai, I'm not really sure at this point. I'm still trying to figure out all the moving pieces. I don't control the AAD side of things. The connection string looks like this:<br/>Data Source=XXX.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=DBName;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: My understanding is that the SID is the critical part of the authentication.   Can you query the sys.database_principals table and see what is recorded in there that might be for this user?

Comment: In traditional SQL Server, not Azure, you would create a single Login for the system and a user for each database you wanted that account to have access too. Say a SQL Server install had 10 databases. For user X I'd make 1 Login and 3 users based on the 3 DBs I wanted him to have access too. In Azure there seems not to be a Login, still learning but that seems to be handled by AAD. In my original post if you note the error message I'm trying to make a USER but getting an error about a LOGIN. It some how related to the single account getting is ID/email changed from Use@ to UseR@.

Comment: @RichP - can you please check on the SID in the sys.database_principals table in the database where you are running this. If the existing user is still there with the OLD name, then try running ```ALTER USER [MyUser@domain.com] WITH NAME = [MyNewUser@Something.com]```  As I said, the SID is the part that actually maps to AAD so you should be able to change the name